# Изменить Label при загрузке файла с фтп (ftp4j) в отдельном потоке

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency, многопоточность

В общем есть JavaFx приложение, которое при определенных условиях начинает скачивать для себя информацию через фтп (использую библиотеку ftp4j)и создает на основе файлов бд. Само собой этот процесс должен происходить в фоновом режиме, и поэтому нужна индикация. Использую ProgressBar и Label.
[image: ProgressBar и Label.]
В ftp4j есть интерфейс слушателя, который реализуется при загрузке какого-нибудь файла:

```
import desktop.Main;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPDataTransferListener;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPFile;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;

public class MyFtpListener implements FTPDataTransferListener {

    int totalTransferred = 0;
    long fileSize;
    FTPFile file;
    float dPart;
    float percentage;
    double defaultProgress;
    ProgressBar pb;
    Label lTD;

    public MyFtpListener(FTPFile file,float dPart){
        this.file = file;
        fileSize = file.getSize();
        this.dPart = dPart;
        pb = Main.getPb();
        lTD = Main.getlTD();

    }

    public void started() {
        System.out.println("File: " + file.getName() + " STARTING DOWNLOAD. SIZE = " + fileSize + " KB");
        defaultProgress = pb.getProgress();
        System.out.println("now progress: "+defaultProgress*100);
    }

    public void transferred(int i) {

        totalTransferred += i;
        percentage = (float) totalTransferred / (float) fileSize;

        Double sum = defaultProgress+((double) percentage* (double) dPart);
        pb.setProgress(sum);
        //lTD.setText(Double.toString(sum*100));
        System.out.printf("\r Transfered: %d KB, %.2f %% ", totalTransferred, percentage*100f);
    }

    public void completed() {
        System.out.println("File: " + file.getName() + " DOWNLOADED SUCCESSFULLY");
    }
    public void aborted() {

    }
    public void failed() {
        System.out.println("File: " + file.getName() + " CANNOT DOWNLOAD");
    }

}
```

В конструктор передается файл и переменная показывающая какой частью от общего объема является текущий файл. После на основе этого считается прогресс.

Для работы использую метод transferred, чтобы "апдейтить" информацию максимально приятно для глаза.
pb.setProgress() - отлично выполняется в отдельном потоке, создаваемом в методе класса Main:

```
public void firstRun(){
        new Thread(()-> {
            System.out.println("INIT FIRST RUN");            
            FtpFilesDownloader ftpFilesDownloader = new FtpFilesDownloader();            
            ftpFilesDownloader.DownloadFilesFromFtp();            
        }).start();
    }
```

Однако при попытке проделать тоже самое в ТекстБоксе вылезает исключение:

> Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on
>   FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5

Понимаю, что ошибка в ТекстБоксе связанна с особенностями многопоточности JavaFx, однако, почему тогда нормально работает прогрессБар?

Также прошу подсказать отпимальный способ решения этой задачи, т.к. не знаю как в этой ситуации правильно применить Task. В частности не могу понять где и как его вызывать.

Заранее большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем ничего менять не пришлось. Просто строчку:

```
lTD.setText(Double.toString(sum*100));
```

обернуть в:

```
Platform.runLater(()-> lTD.setText(Double.toString(sum*100)));
```