# Параллельный вызов метода другого класса Java FX

Tags: java, сервер, javafx

Есть форма и есть статический метод, который реализует запуск многопоточного сервера. Проблема такая, если прописывать вызов этого метода в контроллере, то форма зависает, так как начинает работать данный метод. Каким образом можно сделать обновление интерефейса и параллельную работу сервера? Я так понимаю необходимо разбить выполнение программы на два потока, один, отвечающий за интерфейс, другой за работы сервера, но как это?

Main.java:

```
          import Server.AUTO.Goods;
          import Server.NET.Server;
          import javafx.application.Application;
          import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
          import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
          import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
          import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
          import javafx.scene.Parent;
          import javafx.scene.Scene;
          import javafx.scene.control.Button;
          import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
          import javafx.scene.image.Image;
          import javafx.stage.Stage;
          import java.io.IOException;
          import java.net.URL;
          import java.sql.ResultSet;
          import java.sql.SQLException;
          import java.util.ArrayList;
          import java.util.ResourceBundle;

          import static Server.DATABASE.Database.ExecuteStatement;
          import static Server.DATABASE.Database.GetInformationDatabase;
          import static Server.DATABASE.Database.getInstanceDatabase;
          import static Server.NET.Server.flag;
          import static Server.NET.Server.getInstanceServer;


    public class Main extends Application {

    public Button onServer;

    public Button offServer;

    public static Stage primaryStage;

    public static void setStage(Stage stage)
   {
     primaryStage = stage;
   }

  public static Stage getStage() {return primaryStage;}

  public static void setScene(Scene scene)
  {
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  }

  public static Scene getScene() {
      return primaryStage.getScene();
  }

  public static void runStage(Stage stage) throws IOException {
      primaryStage = stage;
      primaryStage.setTitle("ServerProgram");
      primaryStage.setMinHeight(300);
      primaryStage.setMinWidth(530);
      primaryStage.setMaxHeight(400);
      primaryStage.setMaxWidth(630);
      primaryStage.show();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Server/FXML/Scene1.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    runStage(primaryStage);

}

public void startServer(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
    onServer.setDisable(true);
    flag = true;
    offServer.setDisable(false);
    //Запуск сервера 
    getInstanceServer();
    //ЗАВИСАНИЕ ФОРМЫ
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Platform -> runLater() должен помочь (см. ответ) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468106/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-label-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BF-ftp4j-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: Если "умеете" в английский - здесь все разъяснено http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте обернуть стартование сервера в [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

Таким образом, метод `start` сервер будет выглядеть примерно так

```
public void startServer(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
    onServer.setDisable(true);
    flag = true;
    offServer.setDisable(false);
    //Запуск сервера
    Task < Void > task = new Task < Void > () {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            //тут запускаем, например, прогресс бар
            getInstanceServer();
            return null;
        }
    };
    new Thread(task).start();
}
```